# AccessViolationException when interacting with RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, access-violation

I'm aware there is a bug with .Net 2.0 with LCG which generates `AccessViolationException` when certain `IEnumerable<>` and similar objects are used; and that there is a hotfix.

I have a project in .Net 4.0 using WinForms running on Windows 7 x64. I have a very simple form - nothing but a form and a `RichTextBox` docked to take up the whole client size.

From a background thread, I periodically call an update method on my form that does something *similar to* the following:

```
public static void Log(string text)
{
  Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => {
    lock(richTextBox) {
      richTextBox.Text += text;
    }   
  }));
}
```

I do actually have both the inside of the `invoke` and the outside in a try/catch (Yes, I know this is horrible!) and I'm doing some additional things like putting the caret to the end and scrolling to it. I'm also using `StringBuilder` but this is all beside the point:

Rarely, but inevitably, while debugging, my IDE detects an `AccessViolationException` somewhere in the code that's updating the text box. It's sometimes in the bit that updates the text, it's sometimes at the bit that makes the selection, and it's sometimes at the bit that scrolls to the caret. If I press F5 to continue, I usually don't see the problem for some time and the application continues as before.

There is nothing fancy happening with this text box. There is no race condition (first of all because I have a lock), but also because there is simply nothing in my code that would try and write to the text box at the same time as something else is trying to.

Any idea why this may be happening? I'm sorry, I don't know what other information I can put here, as I'm not even sure why this is happening in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the rest of your code is doing but I reckon the problem is with lock(richTextBox). If the GUI thread is doing something with the RichTextBox, the lock will not work Or if you are accessing this RichTextBox in some other thread.

Comment: No, this is not true. First of all, I added the lock recently and the access violation was happening before and after I added it. Also, there is no "other thread", as I've invoked the updates on the GUI thread. Anyway, locking will never cause the problem you described.